# How do I add comments to an app in the Market?

Tags: google-play-store, app-ratings

Apps in the market have a lot of comments and reviews.  How do I add my own rating and comment to these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Navigate to Market, select Menu > Downloads and you will see the list of apps on your phone. Notice the My Rating section where you can star and comment on the app.

Comment: you don't actually have to be in the "Downloads" section to add comments -- just as long as you navigate to the app. But "Downloads" is the easiest way of finding everything you've .... downloaded.

Answer (score 3):

Once you've actually installed an application, open it up in the Market and the "My Review" section will appear -- you can give it a 1-5 star rating, and then submit comments.

[image]

If you haven't installed (or have uninstalled the app)s, you can only view comments (or mark as spam).

See Also: [Market comment posting policy.](http://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138329)

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear: You cannot add a comment to an app until you have rated it (out of 5 stars). You cannot rate an app until you have installed it.

Once you have installed and rated and app, then you can comment. (Even if you no longer have the app installed.)